# How to prevent server flooding in a Django web application?

Tags: python, django, flooding

I am developing a Python-Django web app. It lets people visiting my site to embed an already created poll widget to their sites. The problem is when a visitor embeds a poll in a site that has much traffic - so that many people vote on the poll at the same time. It can lead to overload and I don't know how to handle that.

**My site is hosted on shared hosting**. The server is Apache with mod_fcgid. Database is MySQL.

Would someone give me a piece of advice what to do in such situation?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to figure out what you want to limit.  I.e. is it database hits that are the problem?  Just raw #HTTP reqs/minute?  Etc.  And then from that determine what you want users to see when you are limiting, and then your ultimate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without getting into rationalizing why you see this is a problem, I suggest you look into one of the many throttling modules for apache, here's a similar question:

[How can I implement rate limiting with Apache? (requests per second)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/apache-rate-limiting-options)

Comment: I see that a problem because as I mentioned my site is on shared hosting. I am not sure if there is a possibility to use one of these modules for Apache... Should I implement some form of **rate limiting** or should I use **threading**, or some sort of **queue**? I just don't want a phone call from the hosting company telling me I have exceeded the resources I have.

Answer (score 0):

I continued investigating on the problem and found the presentation of [Mike Malone (Pownce.com) on "Scaling Django Web Apps"](http://www.slideshare.net/pvergain/scaling-django-dc09). While he talks mostly about really high traffic web apps, some of the pointed solutions can be applied in my sitiation too.

Thank you all for the help!