# Servlet filter: very simple rate-limiting filter allowing bursts

Tags: java, tomcat, servlet-filters, rate-limiting

I'd like to add a very simple filter doing a per-IP rate-limit but still allowing burst, a bit like what the *iptables* allows to do.

I don't want install the entire kitchen sink: all I need is one Filter class implementing that functionality.

What would be a good data structure / algorithm allowing to do a simple "rate-limiting-but-with-short-bursts allowed"?

For example I'd like to serve an HTTP error code if the user tries to do more than 'x' GET / POST per minute, but I'd still like to enable that same user to "burst" up to 'y' (where y > x) until he hits the burst cap.

Just for comparision, here's how a similar rate-limitation-with-a-burst can be configured using *iptables* (it's just an example, to show what I'm talking about, even though in my case it's not about putting a rate-limit+burst on TCP SYN packets):

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m limit --limit 1/s --limit-burst 5
```

Comment: I did some analysis of the requests to Apache's svn server looking at exactly this problem. My conclusion was if the required limit was x reqs/min then implementing a limit of nx every n minutes and select n based on what you view as an acceptable burst traffic profile. I ended up setting the limit per day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At **Java** level :

- Found a rate limiter based on [Esper](https://gist.github.com/1755249) where your build your own query to match your burst requirement.
- Jetty has a built-in servlet [filter](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-servlets/9.3.2.v20150730/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/DoSFilter.java#DoSFilter)
- A Java library with the built-in [blocks](https://github.com/jabley/rate-limit) to create your own mechanism
- [Camel](http://camel.apache.org/throttler.html) has a throttle mechanism

But I think it's easier to implement at **webserver** level

- [Nginx](http://tumblr.jonthornton.com/post/641219929/rate-limiting-with-nginx)
- [Apache Httpd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second)

Or with a dedicated **server add-on**

- [IBM WebSphere DataPower](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/0712_sheikh/0712_sheikh.html#Rate%20limiting)

Comment: It's not easy to implement rate limiting in nginx if the HTTPS session terminates in Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

you can also look at Guava [RateLimiter](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/index.html?com/google/common/util/concurrent/RateLimiter.html) - it provides a nice starting point for more sophisticated ratelimiters.