# Are there any options available to rate-limit rest API using tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, security, tomcat, rate-limiting

I have a simple rest web service developed using spring boot which comes with embedded web servers like tomcat.

I am exploring the options to implement this using tomcat app server at application side or by tomcat web server to manage request before it hits application.

But I cant find the relevant documentations to implement this. Whatever articles I am exploring seems to be old. SO wondering if some one has implemented this functionality recently and where is the relevant documentation available.

I am quite new to web app development and hence need information when can explain from basics.

Comment: Do you have a reverse-proxy or load-balancer in front of Tomcat, or are you looking for a pure-Java/Tomcat solution?

Comment: no, we dont have any other layer. We are planning to use tomcat which come as part of spring embedded servers. And yes I am looking for solutions which can be acheived with the spring tomcat app server and embedded web server. Need not to be pure java.

Comment: Have a look at this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40392253/why-does-tomcat-lack-built-in-rate-limit-filters