# Apache 2.4.1 and old mods

Tags: apache

I have been researching a possibility to upgrade to Apache 2.4.1 and have found that these mods arent compatible with it

- mod_limitipconn
- mod_evasive
- mod_rpaf

Does anyone know whether if there are alternative mods available for 2.4.1 and/or whether if these mod's functionality is included in Apache?

Answer (score 5):

mod_qos is a choice to replace mod_evasive
http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/

note:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/mod-qos/forums/forum/697421/topic/5084013

mod_qos 10.5 compiles with Apache 2.4 BUT: 1) be careful when using QS_Srv* directives (they probably do not work as expected because connection records are cleared after a quite long time) 2) QS_SrvMinDataRate is not available (use http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html instead)

Comment: Can you please let me know, how you made mod_reqtimeout to work. I tried [SlowHttpTest](http://code.google.com/p/slowhttptest/) to test the slow connection and put the following configuration:
`RequestReadTimeout header=20-40,MinRate=2500 body=20,MinRate=2500`
The module is properly loaded and still it did not close the connections, where were supposedly the slow ones.
Do you know what I needed to do, apart from decreasing the Timeout value?

Answer (score 3):

The services of `mod_rpaf` are now provided by Apache natively in [mod_remoteip](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_remoteip.html).  I'm not familiar with the other modules.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be true.