# Limiting number of connections from bottlepy's `run`?

Tags: wsgi, bottle, embeddedwebserver, wsgiserver

Is it possible to limit connections, restrict to certain number of unique IP addresses; with Bottle's `run` command?

All I could find was this: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/deployment.html

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no.

There's no built-in way to do this.  (You didn't include a lot of detail, so I'm making some assumptions about what I think you might have in mind.)  In theory (and *only* in theory--please don't go this route), you could write a Bottle [plug-in](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/plugindev.html) that tracks connections and denies requests depending on certain access patterns.  But there are many reasons you shouldn't.

Instead, you should rely on your web server (the one in which Bottle will run in production--e.g., [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/), [nginx](http://nginx.org/en/docs/)) to handle this.  For example, here's an SO discussion on [rate limiting in Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second).

Sorry there's no "yes" answer; but hope this helps!  Cheers.