# What is the call limit to Magento 2 Rest APIs? (Burst size and Leak Rate)

Tags: api, magento, magento2, magento-2.0

How many calls can I make per second to the Magento 2 Rest APIs. Could not find anything in their documentation.

Shopify has a bucket size of 40 and leak rate of 2 requests/second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rate limiting is not supported by Magento web API itself, but can be configured on Apache level (see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131681/how-can-i-implement-rate-limiting-with-apache-requests-per-second)).